# On hover to show icon ? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want the button to only show up on my hover on selected row ?
Here is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2-j8b2jb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I want to show 'Edit' button only on hover item. Hover on one row example first name

```
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'editing': editing.given_name}">
    <label for="number">First Name</label>
    <input  
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="given_name"
      id="given_name"
      placeholder="Jane"
    />
    <div class="value">{{user.given_name}}</div>
    <button (click)="toggleEdit('given_name')">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="accept('given_name')">Accept</button>
     <button (click)="toggleCancel('given_name')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear... What icon? Is it an icon or a button?

Comment: Sorry my mistake button.

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, basically you want the buttons to appear when you hover the input field. This is very simple to do with CSS, no need for JS for that.

```css
.form-group .buttons {
   display : none;
}

.form-group:hover .buttons {
   display : inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
      
      <input placeholder="Hover over me" />

      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Cancel</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you see my stackblitz code? your logic would show me all the edit buttons, and I just want the edit button that is currently hover..by the way I don't do ngFor so I know easier than this.

Comment: Your Stackbliz code shows and hides all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Check on this code,
Step 1: add class to edit button

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'editing': editing.given_name}">
.
.
.
<button id="onToggleEdit-0" (click)="toggleEdit('given_name')">Edit</button>
.
.
.
</div>
```

Step 2: Add the following CSS to this component,

```
.form-group #onToggleEdit-0 {
    display: none;
}

.form-group:hover #onToggleEdit-0{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Add id value based on the row like how I did,

1st row -> onToggleEdit-0

2nd row -> onToggleEdit-1

etc...,,,

Comment: @Viyay did you see my stackblitz code? your logic would show me all the edit buttons, and I just want the edit button that is currently hover..by the way I don't do ngFor so I know easier than this.