# On hover show single button ? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want the button to only show up on my hover on selected row ? Here is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2-j8b2jb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I want to show 'Edit' button only on hover item. Hover on one row example first name

The problem here is that i just want to see the on hover button not everyone.

```
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'editing': editing.given_name}">
    <label for="number">First Name</label>
    <input  
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="given_name"
      id="given_name"
      placeholder="Jane"
    />
    <div class="value">{{user.given_name}}</div>
    <button (click)="toggleEdit('given_name')">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="accept('given_name')">Accept</button>
     <button (click)="toggleCancel('given_name')">Cancel</button>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'editing': editing.family_name}">
    <label for="street">Last Name</label>
    <input
      
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="family_name"
      id="family_name"
      placeholder="Doe"
    />
    <div class="value">{{user.family_name}}</div>
    <button (click)="toggleEdit('family_name')">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="accept('family_name')">Accept</button>
    <button (click)="toggleCancel('family_name')">Cancel</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On hover to show icon ? Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473322/on-hover-to-show-icon-angular-2)

Comment: Similar but not same.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your css
https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-change-edit2-9sk2xn?file=styles.css

```
.form-group button {
  display: none;
}
.form-group:hover button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```